# Getting Html.Action to render based on parent model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple **Search** Controller which has a **ChildAction** that will display the results on the same page based on its parent's search criteria once posted:

```
  @Html.Action("SearchResults","Search")
```

How do I get the model of the parent, once filled with search criteria, so that I can render the results in the ChildAction? I'm looking for something like **parent.GetModel()**

The ChildAction and the Parent are in the same controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

Send the parent's model :

```
@Html.Action("SearchUserResultGrid", "Search", new {SearchUserViewModel = Model})
```

And consume in the Controller:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult SearchUserResultGrid(SearchUserViewModel parentModel)
    {
        if (parentModel.HasSearchCriteria)
        {
            //TODO Do the search

        }
        else
        {
            return null; //empty results
        }
    }
```